# SQL, using Replace function to find related text

Tags: sql

I am using the following function to search for names:

```
select * from Students where First_Name Like '%' + replace('Jasmin', '%', '[%]') + '%')
```

This function is good enough to find related texts including spaces or texts like "Jasminj" (data entry error). but how to use this kind of query to search for multiple conditions for example: "First Name" and "Last Name".
Finally, is there any better methods to search for related texts? THanks

Comment: can you give a sample and with expected result

Comment: if you have in your database two columns First Name, and last name.
if you entered a name like : Jasmin Swith.
using that replace query if you search for "Ja" , "Jasmin Swith" Name will be included:
select * from Students where First_Name Like '%' + replace('Ja', '%', '[%]') + '%')
Result: Jasmin Swith
>>>>>
but using the equal operation:
$select * from Students where First_Name="Ja"
there will be no results

Comment: so my question is how to use the AND operator to search for First Name and Last Name

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Below query will help you :-

```
declare @Employee Table
(
First_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
Last_Name varchar(20) NOT NULL
) 

Insert into @Employee
values('Jasmin','Smith')
Insert into @Employee
values('Raj','Kumar')


select concat(First_Name,' ',Last_Name) from @Employee where concat(First_Name,' ',Last_Name) Like '%' + replace('Ja', '%', '[%]') + '%'
```

**output : Jasmin Smith**

```
select concat(First_Name,' ',Last_Name) from @Employee where concat(First_Name,' ',Last_Name) Like '%' + replace('ra', '%', '[%]') + '%'
```

**output : Raj Kumar**

You can use the concat function to get the required result.

Comment: not working, Concat is not recognized,
i also tried :
select * from Students where First_Name Like '%' + replace('Jasmin', '%', '[%]') + '%') AND Last_Name  Like '%' + replace('Swith', '%', '[%]') + '%')
and also didn't work

Comment: Try this query : select * from Students where First_Name Like '%' + replace('Jasmin', '%', '[%]') + '%' OR Last_Name Like '%' + replace('Swith', '%', '[%]') + '%'

Comment: anyway how people make search tools using SQL queries? 
is it possible that SQL didn't create a good search tool?

Comment: @yasseral-haj, i'd suggest to read this article: [Understanding Full-Text Indexing in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I had my own understanding